# query from MYSQL to mongodb

Tags: mysql, mongodb, nosql

This is my MYSQL query:

```
SELECT country, vaccines, MAX(people_fully_vaccinated_per_hundred) as vaccinated_precentage
FROM country_vaccinations
WHERE people_fully_vaccinated_per_hundred > 60
GROUP BY country, vaccines
ORDER BY MAX(people_fully_vaccinated_per_hundred) DESC;
```

It basically lists all countries that have fully vaccinated more than 60% of its people, and the types of vaccine offered by that country.

I am trying to do the same on MongoDB:

```
db.country_vaccinations.aggregate([
     {$project: {_id:0, 
                country: 1,
                vaccines: 1,
                people_fully_vaccinated_per_hundred: 1},
    }
    {$match: {"people_fully_vaccinated_per_hundred":{$gt:60}}}
])
```

However, I am not sure why it returns "No Records Found" when i add in the $match to retrieve rows that have "people_fully_vaccinated_per_hundred">60%.

Can someone advise me on what is my mistake? I would really appreciate it, as I am new to noSQL and am not sure why.

Comment: Can you provide a sample document with fake data?

Comment: @MattOestreich hi, attached is the link. I took the data from country_vaccinations.csv! https://www.kaggle.com/gpreda/covid-world-vaccination-progress

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure it does the same, test it before using it, and if doesn't work, give us if you can some sample data and the expected output so we can test it.

```js
country_vaccinations.aggregate(
[{"$match": {"people_fully_vaccinated_per_hundred": {"$gt": 60}}},
  {"$group": 
    {"_id": {"country": "$country", "vaccines": "$vaccines"},
     "vaccinated_precentage": {"$max": "$people_fully_vaccinated_per_hundred"}}},
  {"$sort": {"vaccinated_precentage": -1}},
  {"$project": 
    {"_id": 0,
      "country": "$_id.country",
      "vaccines": "$_id.vaccines",
      "vaccinated_precentage": 1}}])
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, im still not sure why it returns no records found. i suspected that it was because the "people_fully_vaccinated_per_hundred" was a string instead of double, but i used $convert to change the data type, and it still doesn't work. I got the data from country_vaccinations.csv: https://www.kaggle.com/gpreda/covid-world-vaccination-progress?select=country_vaccinations.csv